# Cronometro con milisegundos en c#

Tags: c#, timer

Tengo este código en mi timer. 
Lo que pasa es que al hacer comparaciones con un cronometro no tengo la exactitud requerida, no tengo idea cual puede ser el error.
Necesito hacer un cronometro que me marque m-s-ms.

```
 private void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t1.Interval = 10;
        ms++;
        if (ms == 100)
        {
            s++;
            ms = 0;
        }
        else if (s == 60)
        {
            m++;
            s = 0;
        }
        Step1.Text = m.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + s.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ms.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código inicia el cronometro (el comportamiento esta encapsulado en una clase) y lo detiene al presionar enter.

Cada un mili-segundo muestra por pantalla el tiempo transcurrido.
Al finalizar devuelve el tiempo total transcurrido:

```
    using System;
    using System.Timers;

    namespace ConsoleTimer
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double intervalo = 1;
                Cronometro cron = new Cronometro(intervalo);
                cron.Iniciar();

                System.Console.ReadKey();
                TimeSpan final = cron.Detener();

                System.Console.WriteLine("Transcurridos: " + final.ToString());
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Cronometro : Timer
        {
            private DateTime _inicio;

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="intervalo">En milisegundos</param>
            public Cronometro(double intervalo)
            {
                base.Interval = intervalo;
                this.Elapsed += Tic;
            }

            public void Iniciar()
            {
                this._inicio = DateTime.Now;
                this.Start();
            }

            public TimeSpan Detener()
            {
                this.Stop();
                TimeSpan transcurrio = DateTime.Now - this._inicio;
                return transcurrio;
            }

            private void Tic(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Console.Clear();
                TimeSpan transcurrio = DateTime.Now - this._inicio;
                System.Console.WriteLine(transcurrio.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva como ejemplo. Se agradecen los votos.

Answer (score 3):

Primero creas una instancia de la clase `StopWatch`:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```

Después lo inicias cuando te interese:

```
stopwatch.Start();
```

Por último para obttener el tiempo en minutos y segundos lo formateamos de la siguiente manera:

```
TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

// proceso

TimeSpan end = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

TimeSpan time = end - start;

Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}", time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds);
```